# What is this port on my laptop motherboard?

Tags: laptop, ssd, motherboard, cable

I'm trying to install an SSD into a cheap laptop with a built in eMMc. There is a maintenance hatch on the back of the case, which has a space for a hard drive to fit in – however, I don't have a clue what cable I need.

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to do like this picture, but I'm not sure what I need:

[image]

If it helps, the laptop is an Acer Aspire ES-13 ES1-332.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the part number you need should be `50.GG2N7.004 CABLE.HDD`
and entering just `acer 50.GG2N7.004` pulls up decent results on google. I found this from a [thread](http://community.acer.com/t5/E-F-and-M-Series-Laptops/Acer-Aspire-ES1-132-C37M-Sata-Cable/td-p/471575) on the aspire ES1-132 series laptops but this seems to be a common trend across many acer models. Please verify that the length of the cable you buy is adequate to run across the case in the way you need, if not you may try the part number with different ending digits, e.g. `.005` and `.003` as those will have different bends/lengths. At the core its power pins and data to an hdd format over emmc.

Comment: Please include some more information. As currently worded, your answer is subject to [linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), which would cripple an otherwise helpful answer.

Comment: Updated to create a better artifact.